# A Brief Clarification on Closed set Automatically Being Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory

This maybe a non-sense question -- but just to make sure:

Suppose I prove something about some arbitrary set in $\mathbb{R}$ and find that the set is closed. Because I know the set is closed, it's automatically Borel and can be "assigned" a number using Lebesgue measure. This is correct, right?

I'm asking because I'm proving something about the image of a set under a function. I'm worried that the images can't be measured in the range. But I know that the image is closed.

Comment: Yes. The family of Borel sets is the smallest Boolean algebra $B$ that contains the open sets and such that $\cap C\in B$ whenever $C$ is a countable subset of $B.$.. A Boolean algebra, by def'n, contains the complements of its members, so closed sets are Borel.  There are various (equivalent ) ways to define a Lebesgue (Lebesgue-measurable ) set.   A set $S$ is Lebesgue iff $A\subset S\subset B$ for some Borel sets  $A,B$   such that the outer measure of $B$  \ $A$ is $0.$  If $S$ is itself Borel we may take $A=B=S$.